# Calculate average value between two cell phone recharges

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a cell phone recharge table which is as below.

In that at `UserId,Date` level I have particular user's `Balance` amount, the amount which he consumed at a particular day for `voice` communication and amount that was consumed for `data` (internet) usage.

Whenever the user recharges his account the `Balance` increases.

So I want a query which could help me to find the average `Voice` and `Data` amount/balance between two recharges for each user.

`Recharge Table`

```
+--------+-----------+---------+-------+------+
| Userid |   Date    | Balance | Voice | Data |
+--------+-----------+---------+-------+------+
|      1 | 4/5/2018  |     100 |    10 |   15 |  //Recharge of 100
|      1 | 4/6/2018  |      75 |     5 |   10 |
|      1 | 4/7/2018  |      60 |    10 |   10 |
|      1 | 4/8/2018  |      90 |    10 |   20 | //Recharge of 50
|      1 | 4/9/2018  |      60 |    10 |   20 |
|      1 | 4/10/2018 |      50 |    20 |   30 |// Recharge of 20
|      2 | 4/1/2018  |     200 |    50 |   40 |// Recharge of 200
|      2 | 4/2/2018  |     110 |    20 |   20 |
|      2 | 4/3/2018  |      70 |    20 |   10 |
|      2 | 4/4/2018  |      55 |    10 |   40 |// Recharge of 15
|      2 | 4/5/2018  |      5  |    2  |   2  |
+--------+-----------+---------+-------+------+
```

In the above table

A given day's `Balance` = Previous Day's (`Balance` - SUM(`Voice` + `Data`))

As you can see for UserId `1` 100 gets reduced to 75 (100 - (10 + 15)).

But in the third row(`Date = 4/8/2018`) he recharges by an amount of 50 due to which his balance becomes 90 instead of 40.

So I want to find the average `Voice` and `Data` column between 100 and 90 for `UserId = 1`

Below is the output I want

```
+--------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| UserID | RechageDate | Avg_Voice | Avg_Data |
+--------+-------------+-----------+----------+
|      1 | 4/8/2018    |      8.33 |    11.66 |
|      1 | 4/10/2018   |        10 |       20 |
|      2 | 4/4/2018    |      27.5 |       25 |
+--------+-------------+-----------+----------+
```

I know the question is difficult to understand but I have tried my best to explain it.

Please feel free to ask in case of any ambiguity.

Comment: Are there transactions for the recharges in another table?

Comment: No everything is in same table

Comment: You appear to be double counting the data on the day when the recharge appears.  That doesn't seem right.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Updated the desired table.Now I hope double counting is not included

Answer (score 1):

I have Added two new column to determine the recharge information:
I think you have recharge information in another table, if you can put that information like i did this query will work.

```
DECLARE @tbl table(
    Userid int,
    Date    datetime,
    Balance int,
    Voice int,
    Data int,
    Recharge int,
    RechargeSN int
)

INSERT INTO @tbl(    Userid,    [Date],    Balance,    Voice,    Data,Recharge,RechargeSN) VALUES(1,'4/5/2018'  ,     100 ,    10 ,   15,100,3)
INSERT INTO @tbl(    Userid,    [Date],    Balance,    Voice,    Data,Recharge,RechargeSN) VALUES(1,'4/6/2018'  ,      75 ,     5 ,   10,0,3)
INSERT INTO @tbl(    Userid,    [Date],    Balance,    Voice,    Data,Recharge,RechargeSN) VALUES(1,'4/7/2018'  ,      60 ,    10 ,   10,0,3)
INSERT INTO @tbl(    Userid,    [Date],    Balance,    Voice,    Data,Recharge,RechargeSN) VALUES(1,'4/8/2018'  ,      90 ,    10 ,   20,50,2)
INSERT INTO @tbl(    Userid,    [Date],    Balance,    Voice,    Data,Recharge,RechargeSN) VALUES(1,'4/9/2018'  ,      60 ,    10 ,   20,0,2)
INSERT INTO @tbl(    Userid,    [Date],    Balance,    Voice,    Data,Recharge,RechargeSN) VALUES(1,'4/10/2018' ,      50 ,    20 ,   30,20,1)

INSERT INTO @tbl(    Userid,    [Date],    Balance,    Voice,    Data,Recharge,RechargeSN) VALUES(2,'4/1/2018'  ,     200 ,    50 ,   40,200,2)
INSERT INTO @tbl(    Userid,    [Date],    Balance,    Voice,    Data,Recharge,RechargeSN) VALUES(2,'4/2/2018'  ,     110 ,    20 ,   20,0,2)
INSERT INTO @tbl(    Userid,    [Date],    Balance,    Voice,    Data,Recharge,RechargeSN) VALUES(2,'4/3/2018'  ,      70 ,    20 ,   10,0,2)
INSERT INTO @tbl(    Userid,    [Date],    Balance,    Voice,    Data,Recharge,RechargeSN) VALUES(2,'4/4/2018'  ,      55 ,    10 ,   40,15,1)
INSERT INTO @tbl(    Userid,    [Date],    Balance,    Voice,    Data,Recharge,RechargeSN) VALUES(2,'4/5/2018'  ,      5  ,    2  ,   2,0,1)

--SELECT * FROM @tbl t

SELECT userid, RechageDate  = max(date), Avg_Voice = (cast(SUM(voice) AS numeric) / Count(voice))  , Avg_Data = cast(SUM(Data) AS numeric) / Count(Data) *1.00 
--, t.RechargeSN 
FROM @tbl t
GROUP BY t.Userid, t.RechargeSN
ORDER BY t.Userid
```

Comment: I do not have recharge information in another table

Comment: how do you put the comment in the right side? you are doing group based on recharge information so you need to add that. try to understand my logic and you will able to get your query.

Comment: Okay Thanks.......I just clarified that I do not have any other table for recharge....Appreciate your effort.......Thanks :)

Comment: here is how you can get recharge "Balance - lag(Balance - Data - Voice,1,0)OVER(PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY [Date])"

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't posted any attempt to solve this, but have shown an understanding of the data, I assume you just need to be given a broad strategy to begin following, and you can handle the coding from there.

Using LAG() partitioned by UserID, you can join each row to the previous row.  You already have stated that you understand that  (Balance - SUM(Voice + Data)), so in any CASE where that is not true, then you know that you have found a row where a recharge was done.

You can create an artificial column (eg `HasRecharge`) in a CTE that uses a CASE expression to test this and return 1 for the rows that have a recharge, and 0 for the rows that don't.

Then you can do a 2nd CTE where you SELECT from the first CTE WHERE `HasRecharge`=1 and WHERE there EXISTS() a previous row that also `HasRecharge`=1.  And calculate two additional columns:

A SUM of `Voice` + `Data` between this recharge and the last recharge (again using LAG() but this time WHERE `HasRecharge`=1)

A COUNT of rows between this recharge and the last.

Your final SELECT from the 2nd CTE would get the average simply by dividing the SUM column by the COUNT column.

Answer (score 0):

This problem becomes simpler when you have a flat table containing the day's charge, and the previous day's charge. Note that this will only work if your data set  has a contiguous range of dates.

The following queries will need to be edited of course:

```
Select 
 currentday.Date,
 currentday.user,
 currentday.balance - prevday.balance - (currentday.voice+currentday.data) as charge,
 currentDay.voice,
 currentDay.data,
 --The above column will tell you what the difference 
 --is between the expected balance, and should 
 --resolve to the charge for the day
 GETDATE() as nextCharge
 --leave this empty, use GETDATE() to force it to be a datetime
into ##ChargeTable
from [RechargeTable] currentday
 left join [RechargeTable] prevday
   on DATEADD(d,1,prevday.Date) = currentday.Date
      AND prevday.user = currentday.user
```

Now, we know when the user has charged. The charge column will be positive.

```
Select
 user, 
 date
into ##uniquedates
from ##charge
where charge>0
```

Now that we have the dates, we need to go back to the first temp table and update it with the next dates. (not sure on the syntax on aliasing updates).

```
update ##ChargeTable up
set 
nextCharge = (
    select 
     date 
    from ##uniquedates 
    where up.user == user AND date > up.date
)
```

Now we can do some sub selects back on the table to get the data we need.

```
select 
 user,
 (select 
       avg(voice)
      from ##ChargeTable 
      where user = ct.user 
       and date>=ct.date 
       and date<=ct.nextCharge) as AvgVoice,
 (select 
       avg(data)
      from ##ChargeTable 
      where user = ct.user 
       and date>=ct.date 
       and date<=ct.nextCharge) as AvgData
from ##ChargeTable ct
where nextCharge is not null and charge>0
```